# the code of my android project was destroyed alone, but the source files are intact, I do not understand what's going on

Tags: java, android, project

after generate my apk file, my code is become as shown in this picture https://prnt.sc/lbm72c but I checked my source code and it is intact, how can i fix it?

i remove build folder and idea but nothing has changed

I think my problem comes from [gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v0n5.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I had faced same issues in the past, I could not see my files properly in Android Studio, but if I go to project repo(from file explorer) I could open the java files in any editor and they were not affected. So what I'd done was to move the current source files into another newly made repo(project).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you experience anything weird in Android Studio the first thing to do is `Clean project` and then `Rebuild`. If that doesn't work try `Invalidate caches and Restart`

Comment: I invalidated my caches but nothing changed

Comment: I tried to clean
and rebuild the project but it did not solve anything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something was meseed up into you gradle files.
Can you attach the error you get?

Comment: I posted a screenshot my gradle

Comment: It seems that you need to install some packages from sdk manager.